# How to compare one element of an array with each of the others and create a new group in JavaSript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, hash, grouping

I have the following Array in Java Script:

```
let mainGroup = [ ]
mainGroup[0] = {name: "HARRY", speed: 9}
mainGroup[1] = {name: "GEORGE", speed: 8}
mainGroup[2] = {name: "FAIZAN", speed: 8.5}
mainGroup[3] = {name: "EMIL", speed: 6}
mainGroup[4] = {name: "CHARLIE", speed: 5.5}
mainGroup[5] = {name: "BOB", speed: 5}
mainGroup[6] = {name: "ALEX", speed: 3.75}
```

(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

I want to compare the first element of the array with each of the other elements and  create a new group as follow:
newGroup
{"HARRY": 9, "GEORGE": 8, "FAIZAN": 8.5}

I have to create a new group considering the speed value. All people in the newGroup must be within 1 min/km of each other.

This is my code

```
let newGroup  = {}
newGroup[mainGroup[0].name] = mainGroup[0].speed;
    for (i = 0; i < mainGroup.length; i++) {    
    let difference = mainGroup[0].speed - mainGroup[i++].speed;
        if (difference <= 1) {
        newGroup[mainGroup[i++].name] = mainGroup[i++].speed;
        };
    };
```

But as result I have the following (which is wrong):
{HARRY: 9, GEORGE: 8.5}

Comment: how many groups do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

For sorted arrays, you could check with value and predecessor for a new group.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "HARRY", speed: 9 }, { name: "GEORGE", speed: 8 }, { name: "FAIZAN", speed: 8.5 }, { name: "EMIL", speed: 6 }, { name: "CHARLIE", speed: 5.5 }, { name: "BOB", speed: 5 }, { name: "ALEX", speed: 3.75 }],
    groups = data.reduce((r, { name, speed }, i, a) => {
        if (i && a[i - 1].speed - speed <= 1 ) {
            r[r.length - 1][name] = speed;
        } else {
            r.push({ [name]: speed });
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> [edited] I missed something

If i understood correctly you want something like this:

```js
let mainGroup = [
  {name: "HARRY", speed: 9},
  {name: "GEORGE", speed: 8},
  {name: "FAIZAN", speed: 8.5},
  {name: "EMIL", speed: 6},
  {name: "CHARLIE", speed: 5.5},
  {name: "BOB", speed: 5},
  {name: "ALEX", speed: 3.75}
];

const newGroups = {};

mainGroup.forEach((group, i) => {
  mainGroup.forEach(compare => {
    const comparison = group.speed - compare.speed;
    if (comparison <= 1 && comparison >= -1) {
      newGroups[`group-${i}`] = {
        ...newGroups[`group-${i}`],
        [compare.name]: compare.speed
      };
    }
  });
});

console.log(newGroups);
```

I hope I helped you, let me know if this works!

Comment: It works partially because the same group is repeated more times instead of one.

Have a look at the result of your code:

{group-0: {…}, group-1: {…}, group-2: {…}, group-3: {…}, group-4: {…}, …}
group-0: {HARRY: 9, GEORGE: 8, FAIZAN: 8.5}
group-1: {HARRY: 9, GEORGE: 8, FAIZAN: 8.5}
group-2: {HARRY: 9, GEORGE: 8, FAIZAN: 8.5}
group-3: {EMIL: 6, CHARLIE: 5.5, BOB: 5}
group-4: {EMIL: 6, CHARLIE: 5.5, BOB: 5}
group-5: {EMIL: 6, CHARLIE: 5.5, BOB: 5}
group-6: {ALEX: 3.75}

Comment: Yes, but what are you expecting as complete output, just ` {HARRY: 9, GEORGE: 8, FAIZAN: 8.5}`??? cuz as i understood you want to compare each item with the others, so this will be the output... or do you want to compare only the first item? cuz this solution is for each item, if only need to compare the first item it would be easier, can you specify a little more pls

Answer (score 0):

some issues with your increment operators, this can do the job

```js
const mainGroup = [
  {name: "HARRY", speed: 9},
  {name: "GEORGE", speed: 8},
  {name: "FAIZAN", speed: 8.5},
  {name: "EMIL", speed: 6},
  {name: "CHARLIE", speed: 5.5},
  {name: "BOB", speed: 5},
  {name: "ALEX", speed: 3.75}
];

const newGroup = group => group.reduce((acum, elem, index) => {
  if(index === 0 && elem) acum[elem.name] = elem.speed;
  else if(Math.min(...Object.values(acum)) - elem.speed <= 1 )
  acum[elem.name] = elem.speed
  return acum;
}, {});

test('Grouping if close enough', () => {
  expect(newGroup(mainGroup)).toEqual({HARRY: 9, GEORGE: 8, FAIZAN: 8.5});
});
```

Comment: Joe, your code has an error. Have a look here:

{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 29,
  "colno": 1
}

Comment: Ye I have jest instaled for testing, just delete test function